# Add reverse ForeignKey relation to existing instances from django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

If I create a new model which is a ForeignKey of another, can I update existing instances of "another" to have the new ForeignKeys as I create them? i.e. without going through the individual edit page of each instance of "another"?

Suppose that I have a Car model, and I create a bunch of Car instances filling their details in the django admin:

```python
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

After a year I decide to start renting cars to customers:

```python
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...


class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rented_to = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

If I register Customer in the admin site, I can add new customers, edit their attributes and, using inlines, add new cars that are rented to that customer:

```python
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Car, Customer

class CarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Car
    extra = 3


class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CarInline]

admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

Is there a way to add existing Car instances to a Customer from the Customer admin page, instead of clicking through all the cars and selecting their customers?

I would like to have a ModelMultipleChoiceField with all the car instances when I edit/add a new Customer, or something like the filter_horizontal functionality in M2M fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom form displayed in the view of Customer in django-admin.

defined by that:

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
...
class CustomerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        exclude = ('',)

    some_other_field = forms.ChoiceField( ... )

    # override save method to work as expected

@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fields_you_want_to_display', )
    form = CustomerModelForm
```

And then create the functionality of multiple choice field in the used form and override save methods and it would work. You can modify admin pages as you wish.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin